# Flutter: TextField behave differently from emulator and device

Tags: android, flutter, textfield

The TextField is coded below to only allow digits, decimal and dash (negative number).

```
                          child: TextField(
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Enter the answer',
                        ),
                        controller: _controller,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                          decimal: true,
                          signed: false,
                        ),
                        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                            RegExp('[0-9.-]'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
```

However, emulator and devices shows differently (dash is missing, Samsung device uses default Samsung keyboard)
Using GBoard in the Samsung device will solve the issue.

What is the best practice to solve this issue since other user might have different phone models/keyboards?

Thanks[image: Side by side comparison]